What concentration of vinegar should I use when cleaning computer screens?
Let's begin with a bit of background information. Strictly speaking, 'vinegar' is diluted acetic acid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinegar) and the proportion of this acid in 'distilled white vinegar' is only about 5%. Where I live, supermarkets sell a stronger solution with a concentration of 25%.
Now let's turn to cleaning computer screens and monitors. I have read many articles online which cite a 50:50 mixture of white vinegar and distilled water for cleaning these types of surfaces. For me, this is ambiguous because (as we have seen) vinegar appears to come in different concentrations. Therefore, instead of a ratio, I'd like to know: What concentration of acetic acid would be suitable here?

This reads like 80% ad copy. Please EDIT your post. Remove the fluff. Focus on your specific question, BUT also tell us the research that you have done and what have you tried. Keep in mind that the vinegar you get from the store comes in a variety of concentrations, some quite low, and so your 1:1 ratio is meaningless unless you define the concentration of the inputs. Finally, note that your Title is not the same question as your "therefore, my question is..." ending.

@music2myear, the ad concentration appears to be 20% stronger ;-)

how precisely is a 1:1 (50%/50%) ratio ambiguous? note you will never know how much acetic acid is actually in any given 1 ML of store-bought white vinegar.

Is there a reason you cant just use water?  Or a glass cleaner, like Windex?

@Keltari - do not under any circumstance use Windex to clean your monitor, it could damage its anti-glare coating. Distilled water is an option, yes. But sometimes, you need something more powerful to counter oil-based smudges that pure water won't remove so easily.

@AndrewJackson Ive been using Windex or generic glass cleaners on every monitor since back in the CRT days.  I can honestly say I have used it on easily several hundred screens, if not thousands.  Never had an issue.

I have also used Windex or other glass cleaners for all displays for decades, and not had an issue... that I'm aware of. However, there is substantial amount of opinions online stating that ammonia-based cleaners should never be used, due to the removal of coatings and potential for damage, as previously mentioned. I have not been able to find any specific study or research into this topic, just the same opinion over and over again. Display manufacturers also parrot this same opinion. Generally the advice seems to be to use warm water, with a small amount of dish soap for stubborn areas.

0% vinegar is absolutely horrible for the film on modern monitors.

Windex is a glass cleaner. Most monitors have a plastic overlay, and Windex CAN cause pitting in this overlay.

personally I buy screen cleaner. Its parsimonious in the extreme to try to make your own. if you are gonna pay $100+ for a monitor, why risk hurting it over 45 cents a month?
